# How do I 'send an image back', behind textboxes?

Tags: html, css, image, button, textbox

You can view my problem:

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGoEU.png

That image is covering my login form. How do I get it to move behind the textboxes & sign in button?

This is my code:

```
<img src="C:\Users\George\Documents\HTML\My Local Soccer\pics\icons\gradient box.gif" 
    style="position:absolute; top: 155px; left: 480px; width:auto; height:auto;">
<input type="text" class="tb7" value="Username" style="margin-left: 563px" 
    maxlength="20" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Username') {this.value='';}" />         
</br>
<input type="text" class="tb8"  value="Password" style="margin-left: 563px;"   
    maxlength="20" onfocus="if(this.value =='Password') {this.value='';}"/>
<input type="image" height="25px"   width="67px" style="vertical-align:top;"
    src="C:\Users\George\Documents\HTML\My Local Soccer\pics\icons\sign in.gif" />
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the image?

Comment: Gee, I wonder if anyone is going to mention a `background-image` on the `form` or other containing element? Nevermind, the `img` wasn't included in the source code correctly (within SO's markup).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<div id="form_wrapper" style="background-image:url('img/yellow.png');">
<img src="C:\Users\George\Documents\HTML\My Local Soccer\pics\icons\gradient box.gif" 
    style="position:absolute; top: 155px; left: 480px; width:auto; height:auto;">
<input type="text" class="tb7" value="Username" style="margin-left: 563px" 
    maxlength="20" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Username') {this.value='';}" />         
</br>
<input type="text" class="tb8"  value="Password" style="margin-left: 563px;"   
    maxlength="20" onfocus="if(this.value =='Password') {this.value='';}"/>
<input type="image" height="25px"   width="67px" style="vertical-align:top;"
    src="C:\Users\George\Documents\HTML\My Local Soccer\pics\icons\sign in.gif" />
</div>
```

Enjoy and good luck!

Answer (score 11):

Try with style="z-index:-5;" and position relative or absolute

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is through CSS' z-Index. Basically what it does it define the stacked location of elements. The higher the number, the more on top it is of other elements. Since you did not provide the top HTML for these input fields, I cannot give you a concrete example on how to do this, but I would be happy to help you further if you provide more code.

Comment: Easiest way is `background-image` on the form and forget the `img` element.

Comment: Well...I would say forget about the image completely and do it in CSS/ JS, but then the question wasn't complete enough for me to be enough of a judge of it I suppose.

Comment: Javascript? You only need CSS. See: http://www.cssplay.co.uk/boxes/css3-background.html (Of course, `background-size` isn't supported in IE8 or less, so if the `width` is truly needed, that would need to be taken into account.)

Comment: Owh, I'm sorry for the confusion. There is JS in the code in the question (to remove 'Username'/ 'Password' from the fields when focused on). For the style formatting it is indeed not required.

Answer (score 2):

wrap inputs in a div and and style it with the image in background.

Comment: I assume there's a `form` around it too, but at least this isn't a cockamamie `z-index` suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how your orange rectangle fits into your HTML but elements can be placed in front or behind other elements using the `z-index` style property which you can append to the style attribute.

More information on this can be found here:
http://htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/z-index/

Answer (score 1):

You need to set z-indexes in css.

```
<img src="C:\Users\George\Documents\HTML\My Local Soccer\pics\icons\gradient box.gif" 
    style="position:absolute; z-index: 50; top: 155px; left: 480px; width:auto; height:auto;">


<input type="text" class="tb7" value="Username" style="margin-left: 563px; z-index: 50;position: relative;" maxlength="20"
    onfocus="if(this.value == 'Username') {this.value='';}" />      
</br>

<input type="text" class="tb8"  value="Password" style="margin-left: 563px; z-index: 50;position: relative;"   maxlength="20"
    onfocus="if(this.value =='Password') {this.value='';}" />

<input type="image" height="25px"   width="67px" style="vertical-align:top; z-index: 50; position: relative;"
    src="C:\Users\George\Documents\HTML\My Local Soccer\pics\icons\sign in.gif" />
```

Keep in mind that for using z-index you'll need to specify the position as I did it, even if you want to use the default position.

Comment: That's not the right image; that's the submit button. The `img` itself wasn't included correctly in the SO source markup.

Comment: Next point is that the containing element's position will also influence where it will go; hence, if it is in a `form` with `position: static`, you will then place the `img` in position with whichever element parent to it in the DOM has position. `body` is probably what will take that place, not the obvious effect I assume. In short, `position: relative` should be applied to the `position`ing parent element (`form`? `div`? `fieldset`?). And, y'know, putting it with `background-image` on a containing element instead of an `img` element is "best" IMO.

Comment: Of course. We, the ridiculous z-index-posters, started by assuming to position an input, where you don't know what should happen with later, so replacing it with an backgroundimage wasn't an option. Thanks for additional infos although there may be lots of other what-ifs on this topic.

Comment: It is what the OP asked for, yes (and it wasn't that hard to see the markup wasn't right). It is my opinion that if a solution is requested based on faulty logic to offer the better solution. More markup and `position`ing willy-nilly is a less optimal solution in most cases, but whatever. I've not downvoted any, but it is important to make note about the parent `position`ing, most beginners will not pick this up.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a 'gradient box' as background, you should probably consider using CSS for a similar effect instead.